# Сортировка массивов в php

Tags: php, json

Добрый день , не могли бы вы подсказать как можно сортировать массив по $value.
Делал

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
    return ($a[$value]-$b[$value]);
}
```

Но не помогает

```html
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ib3aj",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Basic Y3VwOmFkbW9z",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: ccd40afa-f514-ca09-a9fb-5f6637be3a17"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$arr = json_decode($response, true);

$i = $_POST['name'];

if ($i == 1) {

foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    echo ($arr[$index]['user']).' '.($arr[$index]['Total']).'<br />';
}
}

elseif ($i == 2) {

foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    echo ($arr[$index]['user']).' '.($arr[$index]['B_1011']+$arr[$index]['B_1012']+$arr[$index]['B_1013']+$arr[$index]['B_1014']).'<br />';
}
}

elseif ($i == 3) {

foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
    echo ($arr[$index]['user']).' '.($arr[$index]['B_1015']+$arr[$index]['B_1016']).'<br />';
}
}

else {
 echo 'ВЫБЕРИ ДРУГОЙ ОТВЕТ';
}

?>
```

Comment: опубликуйте структуру массива, который надо отсортировать, в вашем первом вопросе.

Comment: точнее критерий сортировки

Answer (score 0):

Сортировка по имени:

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b){
   return ($a['user']-$b['user']);
});
```

точно также делается сортировка и по другому критерию, только вместо `['user']` подставляете необходимый ключ ассоциативного массива, по которому надо сортировать.

Например `$a['B_1011']-$b['B_1011']` или `$a['B_2022']-$b['B_2022']`

Comment: Это я понимаю , но тогда мне нужно прописать на каждый массив переменную с сортировкой такого типа , но как сортировать если несколько значений? Например $arr[$index]['user']).' '.($arr[$index]['B_1015']+$arr[$index]['B_1016']

Comment: что значит каждый массив, у вас 1 массив $arr! Дополните вопрос, что в вашем понимании `как сортировать если несколько значений`? дополните вопрос структурой массива до сортировки и после сортировки.

Comment: Извиняюсь , не массив а в переборе. Я не могу понять как делать сортировку по нескольким значениям.    Есть ($arr[$index]['B_1015'] - выводится 1 значение , и есть ($arr[$index]['B_1015']+$arr[$index]['B_1016']) т.е. где 2 значения из массива складываются. Вопрос в том , как сортировать значения которые складываются?

Comment: @heymukki дополните вопрос структурой массива до сортировки и после сортировки.

Comment: А как вывести структуру после сортировки?

Comment: @heymukki вручную напишите.

Comment: Разобрался: return (($b['B_1015']+$b['B_1016'])-($a['B_1015']+$a['B_1016']));

Answer (score 0):

```
return (($b['B_1015']+$b['B_1016'])-($a['B_1015']+$a['B_1016']));
```